# Joining multiple tables from different databases

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am working on ASP.NET core application where I am using Entity Framework to interact with SQL server database. so far, I was using `Scaffold-DbContext` command to create new model from SQL server database. Even if , we wanted to create `DbContext` based on multiple tables, I could do that using `-t` flag in above command. Everything happening on single SQL database.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=XXXXXXXXX;Database=XXXXXXXX;User Id=XXXXX;Password:XXXXXX" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -t Table1 Table2
```

From [Scaffold-DbContext parameters](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet.html#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold) commands, I couldn't find option to specify different databases.

In new scenario, I have to join 2 tables from different SQL databases. Is there a way to create model which is consist of 2 tables from different databases. Both tables are using one-to-one relationship between them.

For example- DB1 has table1 and DB2 has table2. Is there a way to create a `DbContext` which is consist of these 2 tables (table1 and table2)?

Is there any other way to achieve join between 2 tables from 2 different database?

Comment: Joining across databases is not supported in any version of EF. However, you could query each database separately and then join with linq to objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that with EntityFramework (neither 6.x nor Core). A DbContext is per database and you can only do joins within the same DbContext.

You could create a view and map the view to the models you needs, but iirc. mapping of views is still on the roadmap for EntityFramework Core. May work with EntityFramework 6.x though.

**Edit:**

At least you can't doing it with Linq/Fluent api. You can execute [raw queries](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/raw-sql.html) though. The catch: The project must match the model exactly, there can't be any missing fields of the model. The Ad-hoc mapping to non-entities is on the roadmap for future versions of EntityFramework Core

Comment: Thanks @Tseng for suggestions. will give a try using raw queries.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, maybe you could try out the "synonym" in SQL Server, create a "synonym" of the table in other database and from the perspective of EF it can be treated as a local table. I haven't tried it out myself though.