# Resolving - LINQ expression that contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a view that lists the all the users in the AspNetUsers Table that shows everything except one item i would like to add. I use the AspNetUsers table for login purposes only. I also have a users table that holds more information about the user, including the company they belong to. So I am trying to use a query to get that.

I believe that the query is correct however, one of the joins are using different contexts 
ApplicationDbContext for Users and Roles 
GeneralEntities for the User and Company Tables

Is there a way to Join these that maybe i do not see or maybe a different way all together?

Here is my Controller Action:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var usersWithRoles = (from user in context.Users
                              select new
                              {
                                  UserId = user.Id,
                                  Username = user.UserName,
                                  user.Email,
                                  user.LockoutEndDateUtc,
                                  RoleNames = (from userRole in user.Roles
                                               join role in context.Roles on userRole.RoleId
                                               equals role.Id
                                               select role.Name).ToList(),
                                  CompanyName = (from cn in db.CompanyNames
                                                 join usr in db.Users on cn.CompanyId equals usr.CompanyId
                                                 join anu in context.Users on usr.AspNetUsersId equals anu.Id
                                                 select cn.CompanyName).ToList(),
                              }).ToList().Select(p => new ExpandedUserDTO()

                              {
                                  UserId = p.UserId,
                                  UserName = p.Username,
                                  Email = p.Email,
                                  LockoutEndDateUtc = p.LockoutEndDateUtc,
                                  Role = string.Join(",", p.RoleNames),
                                  CompanyName = string.Join(",", p.CompanyName)
                              });


        return View(usersWithRoles);
    }
```

Here is ExpandedUserDTO:

```
public class ExpandedUserDTO
{
    [Key]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Email address is required")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 8)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Password is required")]

    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Lockout End Date UTC")]
    public DateTime? LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }
    public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Job Title")]
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<UserRolesDTO> Roles { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Roles is required")]
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

CompanyNames has a CompanyId --> User has CompanyId & AspNetUserId --> Users Table Id

Update: 
I added the two entities, if that is the proper name for it, to the IdentityModel.
Not sure if this is the proper way to do this or not. I also did not remove them from the other Context.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Users> User { get; set; }

    public DbSet<CompanyNames> CompanyNames { get; set; }
}
```

I still have a small issue i am working on. The query is bringing back all of the Company names in each record. If you see something in the query that would explain that let me know.

Final update:
With a few changes i was able to get this to populate what i needed.. 
Here is the now working Controller query:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var usersWithRoles = (from user in context.Users
                              select new
                              {
                                  UserId = user.Id,
                                  Username = user.UserName,
                                  user.Email,
                                  user.LockoutEndDateUtc,
                                  RoleNames = (from userRole in user.Roles
                                               join role in context.Roles on userRole.RoleId
                                               equals role.Id
                                               select role.Name).ToList(),
                                  CompanyNames = (from usr in context.User
                                                 join com in context.CompanyNames on usr.CompanyId equals com.CompanyId
                                                 join anu in context.Users on usr.AspNetUsersId equals anu.Id
                                                  where (anu.Id == user.Id)
                                                  select com.CompanyName).ToList(),
                              }).ToList().Select(p => new ExpandedUserDTO()

                              {
                                  UserId = p.UserId,
                                  UserName = p.Username,
                                  Email = p.Email,
                                  LockoutEndDateUtc = p.LockoutEndDateUtc,
                                  Role = string.Join(",", p.RoleNames),
                                  CompanyName = string.Join(",", p.CompanyNames)

                              });


        return View(usersWithRoles);
    }
```

I would still welcome input on the Context change i made. Would like to do that correctly. If having them in two different places doesn't matter and it is standard then please leave a comment below!

Comment: **one of the joins are using different contexts** afaik, using different `DbContext` in a single query is not possible (they are designed to point different database). however, assuming your "user table additional info" have the same primary key with the AspNet Membership user table, you can cheat your way using two queries or raw one. otherwise, you need to add the user table into the other `DbContext`. btw see this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39601317)

Comment: So what you are telling me is that I should not put all of my other tables in a different Context? I did it to keep they identity tables and all the rest separate. If it is common practice to only use one context then i will just move everything over to ApplicationDbContext. Is this the standard?

Comment: it depends on the need and usages, however it is certainly easier to have one `DbContext` for one database. see this [QA for more thoughts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45633420).

Comment: I am having a bit of confusion about this.. I have looked at several other projects and they are doing the same thing i am. This is what i am using and from what i have read it is inheriting the same as applicationDbContext. public class GeneralEntities : DbContext. If they are both DbContext then how is it a different context?

Comment: oh, so it inherits the `ApplicationDbContext`? no issue then, just keep using your generic context thing and never call `ApplicationDbContext` directly, given inheriting class exposes parent's public/internal (see on access modifier for more info) fields and methods.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. The Identity tables do not show up through the GeneralEntities. I guess my next question should be. Do i add the identity tables to GeneralEntities or maybe rename my GeneralEntities : DbContext to be GeneralEntities : ApplicationDbContex?? This seems to be a widely known black hole. A lot of questions about this out there and none really show good examples.